# How to view files containing + % # characters in the file name in the asp.net core project with UseDirectoryBrowser

Tags: http, asp.net-core, https, html-encode, directory-browsing

I can seamlessly display files containing these characters when using http. I can't view when I use https. Can I do a view without changing the filenames?

Comment: I failed to reproduce the your issue, could you share more detailed reproduction steps (include the input url and corresponding results)？

Comment: I created the sample project. Project is the default mvc project. After running the project go to the / asset link. Try opening the files one by one. you will see that files with "+ % #" in the filename are not opened. You can access it here 
https://github.com/fdevGit/WebApplication1